# ASP.NET Core 2.0 Razor Pages using AddMvcCore() instead of AddMvc()

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

I'm not a big fan of using the pre-bundled `AddMvc()` and prefer to use the `AddMvcCore()` instead.

Having said that, I was wondering how to go about using the new (as of 2.0) `AddRazorPages()` with `AddMvcCore()`.

For example, if we do a "bare-bones" configuration of middleware to only use `AddRazorPages()` which is found from the [official repository](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc/MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.cs)

```
// loaded the NuGet package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvcCore()
        .AddRazorPages();
}
```

After I created a `foo.cshtml` page and placed it into the `.\Pages\` directory, it is returning a 404 (Page not found) when I navigate to the URL `\Foo`.

**.\Pages\Foo.cshtml**

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages

@functions {
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public string Message { get; private set; } = "In page model: ";

        public void OnGet()
        {
            Message += $" Server seconds  { DateTime.Now.Second.ToString() }";
        }
    }
}

<h2>Hello World</h2>
<p>
    @Model.Message
</p>
```

The sample page above is taken from the [Microsoft Documents: Introduction to Razor Pages in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/?tabs=visual-studio)

> Has anyone figured this out, or know what is missing? I'm thinking there is an issue with the routing.

Comment: I don't think `AddMvcCore` adds any Razor stuff so you would need to add that manually.

Comment: You mean I need `.AddRazorViewEngine()` and `.AddViews()`, etc?

Comment: Not sure exactly what RazorPages needs (not had a chance to play with it yet) but I would start adding items until it works as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out there were two issues.

(1) I needed to run the MVC middleware (duh!)

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ... )
{
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

(2) Then I got an exception thrown, which forced me to have to include `.AddAuthorization()`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvcCore()
        .AddAuthorization()
        .AddRazorPages();
}
```

Here it is super-simplified into a simple Console app:

```
//using System.IO;
//using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
//using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
//using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IWebHost host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddMvcCore()
                .AddAuthorization()
                .AddRazorPages();
        })
        .Configure(app =>
        {
            //app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseMvc();
        })
        .Build();

    host.Run();
}
```

Comment: If I run mvccore + addrazorpages as described in this answer, I still get error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' error.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look at the [source code for `AddMvc`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc/MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L25) we can see that it calls `AddMvcCore` internally and then proceeds to add additional items. So if I were you I would start adding these items in until you get Razor Pages to work, probably focusing on the Razor parts. For example:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvcCore()
        .AddViews()
        .AddRazorViewEngine()
        .AddRazorPages();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to change anything. It's as if the routes are not going where they are supposed to...

Comment: Did you go through and add all of the bits that `AddMvcCore` doesn't?